# How to build with wasm-pack for wasm64 target?

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-cargo, wasm-pack

I've tried so far to

```
[build]
target = "wasm64-unknown-unknown"
```

In .cargo/config.toml,

and `#![cfg(target_arch = "wasm64")]`

in my lib.ts

Still, the `target` directory that I have as a result of `wasm-pack build -t web` is `wasm32-unknown-unknown`.

Is there any way to build `wasm64-unknown-unknown` with `wasm-pack`?

It works for `cargo build`, but as I understand only wasm-pack would generate appropriate bindings for JS.

Comment: wasm64 is a tier 3 target, I don't think `wasm-pack` has ever even considered supporting it yet.

Comment: although it's sad, still, thank you for your comment : )